# User formatable ID with Auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an app that needs to store project IDs (in a MySql DB).  The Admin user should be able to set the format for the ID numbers (#####, ##-####, YY-##-####, etc)...only before any projects are created of coarse.  The ID must also autoinc. when a normal user creates a new project.

I am thinking the auto increment will have to be done with PHP, by reading the last record and adding 1.

Since the ID format will defined by a user, I think it would probably have to be a single field (varchar?).  Or should the app create multiple fields to accommodate the user defined format?  Any thoughts on this?

Looking for any ideas...

Comment: IDs are stored in MySQL DB.  Auto Increment will not work, because of the user definable format.

Comment: if you use database to store ids, then no worries. Get last id then increment it in 1. I do it my project. I can give that code. So you can get an idea. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a primary key `project_id` that is `AUTO INCREMENTED` and that add a special field for the one that the admin may define the format for?

Comment: @KristerAndersson, thats one thought I had, but since ID is user formatted, (some companies for example may use IDs like 12-0123, where 12 is the current year and 0123 would start over at new year) that probably would not work...that is why I am kind of leaning toward a single field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with reading the previous id and just incrementing by one is that you risk repeated use of the same ID. consider:

- You create a new project, which takes its ID from the previous one.
- You use, and possibly distribute the project ID
- You decide you don't want that project after all, and delete it
- You create a new project. The new project will have the same ID as the old, deleted one, because it is derived by incrementing the same source.

If this is not a problem for you, then that is your solution.

Otherwise, you might try this:

- Create two columns in your table - one for the ID, and one for an autoincrementing integer.
- When you create the project, don't add the ID. The integer value will autoincrement
- Fetch that integer value (possibly with mysql_insert_id)
- Update your project with the ID generated from the autoincremented integer

This is more effort for the system to make, and at extremely high volumes you may encounter race conditions, but if you add a Unique index on the project ID, that should catch any issues.